# How to Use Sequelize Class in Front-end TypeScript Code

Tags: typescript, sequelize.js, svelte, sveltekit

I have my Sequelize models set up and working. Here's a simplified example how how I've done it:

```js
//--- db.ts ---
export function db(): Sequelize{
  const sequelize = new Sequelize({
    dialect: 'sqlite',
    storage: 'DB.sqlite'
  })

  Thing.init({
    name:{ type: DataTypes.STRING },
  }, {
    sequelize //connection instance
  })
  
  return sequelize
}

export class Thing extends Model{}
```

I want to be able to use the `Thing` data type throughout my app on both the front-end and back-end so that I get nice TypeScript support in VS Code for the properties available on my `class`.

But when I do this in my front-end code (which happens to be Svelte) I get a type error:

```js
<script lang="ts">
import type { Thing } from '$lib/db'

var thingOne:Thing? = null //<-- !! JSDoc types can only be used inside documentation comments !!
</script>
```

I also get crazy errors and behavior if I ever try and do this:

```js
var newThing = new Thing() 
//Build failure: Could not resolve "pg-hstore" (Sequelize may be choking since I don't use Postgres)
```

I'm relatively new to TypeScript and Sequelize. Am I not allowed to use my `Thing` class throughout my front and back-end JS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sequelize wants access to the database (via NodeJS api's) and is not available in the Frontend.

A type import:  `import type { Thing } from "$lib/db";` should be allowed,
this statement is removed after typescript compilation.
But is it only for type checking, and because real class can't be used it's not very useful.

Comment: I see. So should I use `sequelize.define` and not use a `class` in my model definitions, and then create my own separate `class` for type checking?

Comment: Using sequelize.define or class doesn't matter, in the sveltekit endpoints (running in nodejs) you can use sequelize however you like, but inside the svelte components its not a sequalize object.  It just json data that you returned from the endpoint  in `{body:`